# Changing momentjs date object format to another

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am in need of changing `moment()` object to other format. For example i receive date in this format, `'yyyy-mm-dd'`, and i need to change it to `'yyyy mm dd'`. I'm currently using this solution and i want to know is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
let dateValue = moment(moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY MM DD'), 'YYYY MM DD');
```

**EDIT:**

So it seems the problem wasn't in moment objects being different. Here's my full code:

```
class EditRelation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { validFrom, validTo } = props.relationMember;

    this.state = {
      validFrom: moment(validFrom, 'YYYY MM DD'),
      validTo: moment(validTo, 'YYYY MM DD'),
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const { id, type, value } = e.target;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (type == 'date') {
      const dateValue = moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      if (id == 'validTo' && dateValue < moment()) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ [id]: dateValue });
    } else {
      this.setState({ [id]: value });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { validFrom, validTo } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref={(form) => { this.form = form; }}>
        <Label for="validFrom"><FormattedMessage id="RELATION_EDIT_MODAL.ACTIVE_FROM" /></Label>
        <Input
          type="date"
          name="validFrom"
          id="validFrom"
          value={validFrom.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Label for="validTo"><FormattedMessage id="RELATION_EDIT_MODAL.ACTIVE_TIL" /></Label>
        <Input
          type="date"
          name="validTo"
          id="validTo"
          value={validTo.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

When changing date input value, i get `The specified value "Invalid date" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".` I though that it was because moment object formats differ, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It looks like you are using moment to convert from one string to another string. Do you actually need the moment object or just the string?

Comment: I need the object not the string.

Comment: what do you mean "need of changing moment() object to other format"? moment represent a date. it can create a string representation if the date at different formats, but the object itself is always the same.

Comment: @GuyYogev You're right the problem wasn't there, i've edited my question with full code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify a format until you are ready to output the date to something like a string. This is super redundant:

```
moment(moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY MM DD'), 'YYYY MM DD')
```

Because you are taking your original object -- `moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` -- converting it to a string with `.format()` and the creating the same moment object from that string. You end up with the same object you would have by simply using:

```
 let dateValue = moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You just need to wait until you have to print a string or do something else that needs a specific format, then call:

```
dateValue.format('YYYY MM DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, It's better to do it without modules because it shows your problem-solving skills and you will get more confidence. You can do it using for loop:

```
var date = '1999-03-10'

for(let i = 0; i < date.length; i++)
    if (date[i] == "-")
        date[i] = " "

console.log (date)
```

Comment: If you're just operating on the string, why wouldn't you just use `date.replace(/-/g, ' ')`

Comment: I don't agree - in production code I would always use a module rather than rewrite from scratch (unless I'm actually a student, but the questioner doesn't say that).

Answer (score 0):

```
    let parsedDate = moment('2014-02-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log('parsedDate', parsedDate); // moment object

    let dateInNewFormat = parsedDate.format('YYYY MM DD');
    console.log('dateInNewFormat', dateInNewFormat); // date string in new format
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const value = '2017-10-24'
const date = moment(value).format('YYYY MM DD')
//2017 10 24
```